# Why is XGBRegressor prediction warning of feature mismatch?

Tags: python, nan, xgboost, imputation

I want to use XGBRegressor to predict some data. So I load the training data and the test data.

```
iowa_file_path = '../input/train.csv'
test_data_path = '../input/test.csv'

data = pd.read_csv(iowa_file_path)
test_data = pd.read_csv(test_data_path)
```

Contents of data

[image]

Contents of test_data

[image]

Then I do some data cleaning

```
data.dropna(axis=0, subset=['SalePrice'], inplace=True)
y = data.SalePrice
X = data.drop(['SalePrice'], axis=1).select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])

train_X, val_X, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X.values, y.values, test_size =0.25)
my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
train_X = my_imputer.fit_transform(train_X)
val_X = my_imputer.transform(val_X)

my_model = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=100, learning_rate=0.1)
my_model.fit(train_X, train_y, early_stopping_rounds=None, 
    eval_set=[(val_X, val_y)], verbose=False)

test_data_process = test_data.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
predictions = my_model.predict(test_data_process)
```

But I get the following error message when running `predict` function:

> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 test_data_process = test_data.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
>   ----> 2 predictions = my_model.predict(test_data_process)
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost-0.80-py3.6.egg/xgboost/sklearn.py in predict(self, data, output_margin, ntree_limit, validate_features)
>       395                                           output_margin=output_margin,
>       396                                           ntree_limit=ntree_limit,
>   --> 397                                           validate_features=validate_features)
>       398 
>       399     def apply(self, X, ntree_limit=0):
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost-0.80-py3.6.egg/xgboost/core.py in predict(self, data, output_margin, ntree_limit, pred_leaf, pred_contribs, approx_contribs, pred_interactions, validate_features)
>      1206 
>      1207         if validate_features:
>   -> 1208             self._validate_features(data)
>      1209 
>      1210         length = c_bst_ulong()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost-0.80-py3.6.egg/xgboost/core.py in _validate_features(self, data)
>      1508 
>      1509                 raise ValueError(msg.format(self.feature_names,
>   -> 1510                                             data.feature_names))
>      1511 
>      1512     def get_split_value_histogram(self, feature, fmap='', bins=None, as_pandas=True):
>
> ValueError: feature_names mismatch: ['f0', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9', 'f10', 'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f20', 'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f25', 'f26', 'f27', 'f28', 'f29', 'f30', 'f31', 'f32', 'f33', 'f34', 'f35', 'f36'] ['Id', 'MSSubClass', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath', 'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Fireplaces', 'GarageYrBlt', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF', 'EnclosedPorch', '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'MiscVal', 'MoSold', 'YrSold']
>   expected f9, f6, f14, f27, f18, f7, f8, f23, f17, f22, f35, f0, f28, f29, f20, f31, f36, f25, f11, f21, f12, f24, f34, f10, f5, f32, f15, f26, f30, f1, f2, f16, f19, f3, f4, f33, f13 in input data
>   training data did not have the following fields: BsmtUnfSF, 1stFlrSF, LowQualFinSF, MSSubClass, WoodDeckSF, GrLivArea, MiscVal, YearBuilt, BsmtFinSF1, Fireplaces, MoSold, BsmtHalfBath, GarageYrBlt, FullBath, PoolArea, YrSold, HalfBath, 2ndFlrSF, KitchenAbvGr, OverallQual, Id, EnclosedPorch, ScreenPorch, GarageArea, BsmtFullBath, MasVnrArea, TotRmsAbvGrd, OverallCond, BedroomAbvGr, GarageCars, OpenPorchSF, YearRemodAdd, TotalBsmtSF, BsmtFinSF2, LotFrontage, 3SsnPorch, LotArea

It complains that the feature mismatches and that I do not have those fields in the training data. But when I check on content of `data`, it has those columns. How to resolve it ?

Comment: You haven't used SimpleImputer on the test data. Is there any data missing there? You can also have a look at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2334

Comment: Yes you are right. I've just run the SimpleImputer and now it works. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close the question:

The problem is that `SimpleImputer` was used on the training and validation data, but not on the test data.

A discussion of what can cause this kind of error can be found here: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/2334#issuecomment-333195491